# Creating a new iframe is considerably faster than setting a source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, iframe

EDIT: I created a fiddle to show the different in load times (ignore any visual css bugs :p) https://jsfiddle.net/ayygn8ft/1/

Has anyone encountered this behavior before? Consider I have the following HTML file:

```
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/viewer.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- IMPORTANT CODE SECTION IS RIGHT HERE -->
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light bracket-button not-transition">
            Click Me
        </button>
        <div id="frame-overlay" class="scale-transition scale-out card">
            <iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>
            <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <!-- END IMPORTANT CODE SECTION -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/viewer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I have pre-defined an iframe with the id `#frame`. Now inside my JS I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showGG = false;

    $('.bracket-button').click(function() {
        showGG = !showGG;
        if (showGG) {
            $('#frame-overlay').removeClass('scale-out');
            // Set source
            $('#frame').attr('src', source);
            $('#frame').show();
        } else {
            $('#frame-overlay').addClass('scale-out');
            // Remove source
            $('#frame').attr('src', '');
            $('.loader').show();
        }
    });
});
```

This code above works, but it's pretty slow to load the iframe. I found that if I instead **remove** the initial frame, and append/remove the iframe on the fly, it loads really quickly:

```
        if (showGG) {
            $('#frame-overlay').removeClass('scale-out');
            $('#frame-overlay').append('<iframe id="frame" src="' + source + '"></iframe>')
            $('#frame').show();
        } else {
            $('#frame-overlay').addClass('scale-out');
            // Remove source
            $('#frame').remove();
            $('.loader').show();
        }
```

Why would adding and removing an iframe load so much faster than setting a source? My initial impression would have been that setting the source would be faster, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: I did not notice any major differences. Developer tools shows me that both codes load page in 900-1000ms. Using Chrome 61.

Comment: @bigless The code is for a twitch extension, so I guess it's something about running within twitch's environment that causes this lag?

Comment: **actually** , it seems to be the specific links I am attempting to load. Set the source in the fiddles to *https://smash.gg/tournament/gametyrant-expo-2017/attendees* @bigless , you should see an obvious load difference

Comment: I noticed only two patterns: cache and sometimes slow load time of external resource like geo, maps etc..but thats normal. Generally slow first time, fast second time - it explanes browser cache. What about some chrome extension or so..? Else I really dunno..